# Delete dictionary from JSON based on condition in Value - Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have JSON as follows

```
dict =[
{'name':'Test01-Serial01'
},
{'name':'Tests04-Serial04'
}
]
```

First I wanted to separate the name with `-` and then with the index 0 that is `Test01`
I wanted to delete the dictionary which don't follow the rule in `name`
Rule: 4 Digit **Word** 2 Digit **Number**

Here Tests04 doesn't follow 4 Digit **Word** 2 Digit **Number** rule and it contains 5 digit word.

Comment: Don't use built-in function names as variables especially when you're using dict to represent a list!

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that validates the value according to your rules. Reconstruct the original list with a list comprehension.

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits


def isvalid(s):
    return len(s) == 6 and all(c in ascii_letters for c in s[:4]) and all(c in digits for c in s[4:])


_list = [
    {'name': 'Test01-Serial01'},
    {'name': 'Tests04-Serial04'}
]
_list = [e for e in _list if isvalid(e['name'].split('-')[0])]

print(_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'Test01-Serial01'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I just edited my question. I wanted to split the name with - and then I need to follow the rule, In that case what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions to parse the values:

```
import re

mylist = [
    {'name': 'Test01' },
    {'name': 'Tests04' }
]

regex = re.compile(r'^\w{4}\d{2}$')
mylist = [{k:v} for _ in mylist for k,v in _.items() if regex.match(v)]

# Or, maybe this is more clear?
# mylist = [item for item in mylist if regex.match(list(item.values())[0])]

print(mylist)
```

This returns:

```
[{'name': 'Test01'}]
```

This says to look for four "word" characters then two digits between the start and end of the value of each object. Anything that doesn't match this pattern is filtered out. Check out the definition of `\w` to make sure that you and the authors of `re` agree on what word chars are.

And, as @cobra pointed out, using `dict` as a variable name (particularly for a list) is not best practice.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I just edited my question. I wanted to split the name with - and then I need to follow the rule, In that case what I should do?

Comment: With `\w` you will also accept a value like "123456".

Comment: @Matthias - yes. that's why i said to check.

Comment: @moses - in that case update the `regex` to match what you need. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html